# Why cant create file inside nginx container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

What i want do is create container and create file inside the container. so thought first try would be to list files so i ran.
`kubectl run test-nginx --restart=Never --image nginx:alpine -- /bin/sh -c "ls"`.
It works as expected. Next would be `kubectl  run test-nginx --restart=Never --image nginx:alpine -- /bin/sh -c "touch index.txt"`. But it fails saying `Error`. why it cant just create file inside the container. Am i missing something ?

Comment: I'm surprised that you say your `ls` example works, since the nginx:alpine image doesn't have bash installed. Try using `/bin/sh` instead.

Comment: sorry for type its sh @HansKilian

Comment: As asked in the answer section: could you please provide the complete error message?

Comment: I got the solution. we need to use sh for nginx:alpine

Comment: "Create a file in a container" isn't usually a useful goal.  In the example you've shown here, you're creating two separate Pods with two separate containers and two separate filesystems.  In normal use you'd run Deployments that have multiple identical replicas, and the cluster can automatically terminate them in some circumstances.  You might look into building a custom Docker image to run your application instead (starting `FROM nginx`, then `COPY` your built front-end code in).

Answer (score 2):

Use `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`

As of this writing, the nginx:alpine image from dockerhub doesn't have /bin/bash.

I'm not sure why `kubectl run test-nginx --restart=Never --image nginx:alpine -- /bin/bash -c "ls"` works for you, unless the image is a custom one..